# Адаптация кода с Java на C#

Tags: java, c#

Добрый вечер господа, нужна помощь человека который хорошо разбирается в Java с целью анализа имеющегося исходного кода программы, так как хочу сделать аналог этой программы на C# но мне никак не удаётся понять логику программы на Java.

[Исходник](http://rgho.st/6wThDx8vB)

Господа мне просто необходимо вычленить основные классы(с их логикой) и отрисовкой. Минимальное содержание.

Заранее спасибо !

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что тут не бюро переводов

Comment: не думаю, что найдется много желающих качать какие то архивы, распаковывать и вникать, не говоря уже о том, что сам вопрос не формат на этом ресурсе. Можете попробовать разместить непонятный кусок кода (не все исходники) прямо в вопросе, тогда может кто то и скажет, что он делает

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть в сторону автоматических конвертаторов, например `JavaToCSharp`.
Может он и не покроет весь код программы, но думаю может облегчить конвертацию.

https://github.com/paulirwin/JavaToCSharp